# Reserve space on my screen for Conky in Xfce

Tags: linux, window-manager, xfce, conky

I'm trying to make Conky act as a panel so that it reserves space for itself correctly. The problem is, if I have

```
own_window_type panel
own_window_hints above
```

([source](https://superuser.com/questions/565784/can-conky-remain-always-visible-alongside-other-windows)) in my `.conkyrc`, maximized windows are either placed way too far down or don't show up on my screen. I have to manually unmaximize the windows in my taskbar plugin on the panel to actually see the window.

Since Conky doesn't place the struts in the correct place, I need some other way. I could put a transparent panel under it, but I'm not satisfied with the result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out:

Under Xfce's Workspace settings, under the *Margins* tab, it says:

> Margins are areas on the edge of the screen where no window will be placed

What I didn't realize before is that this also applies to maximized windows. So you can safely put Conky on the desktop and maximized windows won't cover it, but if you move any windows into that margin, they'll still cover up Conky. There's nothing wrong with that though. Personally, I would much rather have that than windows going *under* Conky.

**Instructions**

1. Open up your `.conkyrc` in your favorite text editor.
2. From there, you can change `own_window_type panel` to `own_window_type override` and comment out the `own_window_hints` line. This will put Conky on the desktop.
3. Save the file and close the text editor.
4. Open up Settings Manager.
5. Go into *Workspaces* under the *Personal* section.
6. Under the *Margins* tab, set the right margin (or left, depending on which side you have Conky on) to the width of your Conky plus 2 `gap_x`'s (e.g. my Conky's width is 140 and `gap_x` in my `.conkyrc` is 10, so enter 160).

Now Conky will stay out of the way if you need it to and you'll still see it if you have any maximized windows.